# Origen y significado de "dormir a pierna suelta"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología, expresiones

El otro día vi a mi hijo durmiendo en la cama destapado, panza arriba, con los brazos y las piernas estirados cada uno en una dirección, y pensé que estaba durmiendo a pierna suelta.

Al buscar la expresión en el diccionario, encontré:

> **[a pierna suelta](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SxJ7E4i#9qipr61)**
>
> 1. loc. adv. coloq. Sin preocupación, tranquilamente. *Dormir a pierna suelta.*

La verdad es que la imagen mental que me produce la expresión difiere de la expuesta. Mi hijo suele dormir todas las noches sin preocupaciones y tranquilamente, pero cuando lo veo durmiendo de lado o boca abajo no pienso que esté durmiendo a pierna suelta. Para mí es algo más postural que otra cosa.

Es posible que mi interpretación de la expresión no sea la correcta, por lo que me gustaría preguntar: ¿cuándo consideráis vosotros que alguien está durmiendo "a pierna suelta"?

Y como preguntas añadidas:

- ¿Se usa "a pierna suelta" con otro verbo que no sea "dormir"?
- ¿Cómo se originó la expresión, cuyo precursor en el diccionario de Covarrubias es "dormir a pierna tendida" (y con el significado de "con descuido")?

Answer (score 4):

No tengo fuentes, pero siempre he interpretado que la expresión viene del estado de relajación en que entran los músculos del cuerpo cuando alguien está profundamente dormido.

Cuando alguien duerme a pierna suelta, puedes literalmente coger su pierna, alzarla un poco y soltarla de nuevo; y ésta caerá sin que el durmiente haga nada por evitarlo, porque la tiene relajada, suelta.
Cuando el sueño es poco profundo, o intranquilo, o un duermevela, si hiciésemos eso mismo la pierna ofrecería resistencia a ser alzada, o bien el durmiente la apartaría o movería (suponiendo, claro, que no se despierte y ya está).

Answer (score 4):

Yo como @walen, tenía mi teoría bastante similar. Cuando uno duerme profundamente tiene los músculos relajados y a veces una  pierna o un brazo cuelgan de la cama.

Por internet he encontrado una [teoría](https://blogs.20minutos.es/yaestaellistoquetodolosabe/cual-es-el-origen-de-la-expresion-dormir-a-pierna-suelta/) que dice que viene del mundo carcelario: antiguamente era costumbre que los presos llevaran grilletes y en ocasiones, como premio por buena conducta, se les permitía dormir sin los grilletes, con lo que descansaban mucho mejor.

Si la expresión original, como dice @CarlosAlejo, es *dormir a pierna tendida* ya no funciona tan bien esa historia de los presos.

Sobre si se usa con otros verbos yo no lo he escuchado nunca pero se pueden encontrar textos con ***roncar/jugar/reirse/vivir/correr** a pierna suelta*. No parecen muy comunes de todas formas salvo quizá *roncar a pierna suelta* ya que el significado es el mismo que con *dormir*.